# JAVA FEST Can't find OptionsPane

Tags: java, swing, fest

I am trying to get Java FEST to find a pop up dialogue and click on the the yes button.
I have the following code:

```
JOptionPaneFixture fixture = JOptionPaneFinder.findOptionPane().using(TestSite.myRobot);
fixture.buttonWithText("Yes" ).click();
```

On the first line the following exception is thrown:

*org.fest.swing.exception.WaitTimedOutError: Timed out waiting for component to be found using matcher org.fest.swing.core.TypeMatcher[type=javax.swing.JOptionPane, requireShowing=true]
Unable to find component using matcher org.fest.swing.core.TypeMatcher[type=javax.swing.JOptionPane, requireShowing=true].*

The option pane of course did pop up on my gui, yet FEST doesn't find it.

I tried using the window finder as mentioned here:
[FEST Swing new frame on click, can't make new frame fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626357/fest-swing-new-frame-on-click-cant-make-new-frame-fixture)

But to no avail!!

Please help!

Comment: Are you using a background thread for this?

Comment: There is the multithreaded gui program and the test is running on a seperate thread. I have a sleep call before calling the finder.

Comment: But you're absolutely sure that the call to set the JOptionPane visible and the code above are on two completely distinct threads, right?

Comment: yes. This part of an automation test. So the JOptionPane's visibilty configuration is not in the test code. Maybe in the gui code i need to correctly pass the parent frame of my OptionPane popup when I create it?

Comment: Yup the problem was a null parent frame

Comment: argh, good pick up. It's always the little things that get you. Thanks for letting us know how you resolved this. 1+ You might want to post your comment above as an answer for the benefit of future coders who run into the same problem.

Comment: @whomaniac please post your comment as an answer and accept it to make your question useful to other StackOverflow users.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that you could use AssertJ Swing in future; FEST is outdated and not maintained anymore. AssertJ Swing is the fork of FEST so the transition will be easy. Even if the development speed is slow, it is being maintained ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must recognize type of element, that you want to find.

For example, I use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` and its create an object of `javax.swing.JOptionPane`.

But, by default `JOptionPaneFinder.findOptionPane()` find not `javax.swing.JOptionPane`.

For fix, you must use this:

```java
JOptionPane t = (JOptionPane) managerFixture.robot.finder().find(c -> c instanceof JOptionPane);
```